# Bamboo Plan script unable to run regex inside bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, bamboo

I am new to Bamboo Atlassian environment. I have a question regarding implement Bash script under plan/branch on Bamboo.

I am trying to run a regex inside script stage but I am getting an error:

> /tmp/SW-2636-ScriptBuildTask-4921335221935380637.sh: [[: not found

My code:

```
if [[ ${bamboo.planRepository.branchName} =~ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+R ]]; then
    do Blah Blah
else
    do something else
fi
```

I have also tried with singe [] instead of [[ ]] but didn't get. 
I ran this script independently as a Bash script and its running fine. Unable to understand how to add regex inside if condition over Bamboo.

Any suggestion/example would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make a trick:

```
if [ "$(ps -p "$$" -o comm=)" != "bash" ]; then
    bash "$0" "$@"
    exit "$?"
fi
```

Add this script at the top of your script to make Bamboo Bash compatible.